# How to change key assignment windows embedded handheld 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile

I am trying to assign the PPT (push to talk) button of an AIRO WIRELESS I-Safe 28 to be usable when a determined application requires it to. However this application does not provide the option to select the PPT button as part of the available keys to select.

My idea is to try to assign this PPT button to be one of the keys that are available in the application from the operating system.

To try to be more clear:

1. The application has the option to select from 4 different keys (buttons)
2. PPT is not one of them
3. I want to (at OS level or registry level) define the PPT button as if it was one of the buttons that IS available.
4. Use the PPT button as intended.

I have been trying to Google this but I haven't had any luck yet.

Thanks for any idea you may have.

Technical details:

1. Phone: Airo Wireless I-Safe 28
2. OS: Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find any SDK or developer information for Airo Wireless I-28. Normally, key remapping or assignment is part of developer kits for such devices.

Hardware keyboard drivers may have been implemented with a mapping table in the registry. But without developer info it is hard to find those and change them to your needs.

So possibly the standard way of key assignments is supported on this device. See Start-Settings-Personla-Buttons. There should be a list of hardware buttons (also called APP keys as they implement VK_APPx keyboard messages). If you are lucky, the PTT (not PPT, or?) key is listed there too. In the buttons settings you can assign a key to an application (installed below \Windows\StartMenu\ProgramFiles). Everytime you press the button, the assigned application will be launched or come to the foreground. Normally there is a button mapped to the Recorder application.

If you find the PTT button in button settings, you can assign it to a custom application. That custom application could then fire just a named event that you can watch in your code.

If the PTT button is not listed there, check if the PTT button is a normal button which sends a keyoard message (VK_...). You may check this with my keytest3ak tool from http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2009/05/11/keytest3ak-a-tool-to-look-at-keyboard-codes/.

If the button does not fire any keybd message, you are lost without any developer application by Airo. Possibly the button fires a named event or triggers anything else that fires the PTT application of Airo.

Please let me know your findings about the PTT button in Settings/Buttons and KeyTest3AK.

Comment: Hi @josef - I spoke with the Airo support team and they will be sending me the developer info to be able to trace the mapping in the registry. Do you have any recommendation on tools to modify the registry on this mobile devices?

Comment: For remote regitry editing I am using CeRegEdit freeware (uses activesync). But there is also a remote reg edit within the windows mobile sdk tools. See Visual Studio Remote Tools.